# Can you use an ACE in a straight as a high card

Tags: texas-hold-em

Ex:

7,8,9,10,A

Or can it only be used as like A,2,3,4,5

Comment: The first example is not a straight.

Comment: Please learn the game basics before posting like this. They are pretty clear on what constitutes a straight

Comment: I voted to reopen because the question involves the particular nature of an Ace in determining hands, something that really was not covered well in the duplicate post. If someone else would second the notion I will write an answer for the OP.

Comment: @Jon My answer on the duplicate covers it.  "Five sequential cards. Ace is both high and low. Ace through 5 is often called a wheel. Ace through 10 is often called Broadway."

Comment: One thing is creating volume. Another thing is creating duplicate volume and questions lacking the bases. Try an analogous question in Stack Overflow. Both things are not contradictory and I am willing to help + UV any user with any question beyond basics.

Comment: E.g. questions with odds, questions about same-rank hand comparison, questions about strategic concepts, questions about tournament rules,...

Comment: I'd even allow and UV (poker-related) book recommendations or identification, though I dont know if community here agrees with that about books.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Never mind

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  but it must be A, K, Q, J, 10.